# Calculate Riemann integral

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

**Calculate Riemann integral:**
$$\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{3} \frac{\arctan(x)}{x^2-x+1}dx $$

In this assignment, the integrand function does not have an antiderivative.  I used the substitution of $x=\frac{1}{t}$ and the fact that $\arctan(x) +\arctan \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) = \frac{\pi}{2} (x \neq 0, x \in \mathbb{R})$ and reduced the integral from the task to the following form:

$$
\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{3} \frac{\arctan(x)}{x^2-x+1}dx = \int_{3}^{\frac{1}{3}} \frac{\arctan(\frac{1}{t})}{\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{1}{t}+1} \left(-\frac{1}{t^2} \right)
dt
= \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \int_{3}^{\frac{1}{3}} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{1}{t}+1} \left(-\frac{1}{t^2} \right)
dt - 
\int_{3}^{\frac{1}{3}} \frac{\arctan(t)}{\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{1}{t}+1} \left(-\frac{1}{t^2} \right)
dt=
$$
$$
= \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \int_{3}^{\frac{1}{3}} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{1}{t}+1} \left(-\frac{1}{t^2} \right)
dt - \int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{3} \frac{\arctan(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2-x+1}dx \ \left( * \right)
$$

I'm stuck on this. I calculated this integral on a calculator in Wolframalpha and it gives out that the value of the integral
$$\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{3} \frac{\arctan(x)}{x^2-x+1}dx 
= \frac{\pi}{4} \cdot \int_{3}^{\frac{1}{3}} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{1}{t}+1} \left(-\frac{1}{t^2} \right)
dt
= \frac{\pi}{4} \cdot \int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{3} \frac{1}{x^2-x+1} dx
$$

But I don't understand how to get this result from the step $\left( * \right)$ where I left off.

I will be glad if you tell me what to do after $\left( * \right)$ or suggest another way to calculate the integral.

Comment: The integral on the LHS also appears on the RHS in $(*)$, so that you gather them together on the left before dividing by 2.

Comment: Can you please tell me a little more in detail how I can gather them together on the left before dividing by 2?

Comment: Doug got ahead of my explanations with this answer ;)

Comment: @Abezhiko, sorry bro.  Your insight inspired me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let
$$I_1=\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{3} \frac{\arctan(x)}{x^2-x+1}dx$$
and $$I_2=\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{3} \frac{\arctan(\tfrac1x)}{x^2-x+1}dx.$$
In the first equality you showed that $I_1=I_2.$ Then, I guess you tried to do the trick $I_1=\frac{I_1+I_2}2...$
$$I_1=\frac12\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{3} \frac{\arctan(x)+\arctan(\tfrac1x)}{x^2-x+1}dx\\
=\frac12\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{3} \frac{\frac{\pi}2}{x^2-x+1}dx\\
=\frac{\pi}4\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{3} \frac{4}{(2x-1)^2+3}dx\\
=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt3}\arctan(\tfrac{2x-1}{\sqrt3})\vert_{1/3}^3\\
=\frac\pi{2\sqrt3}(\arctan(\tfrac5{\sqrt3})-\arctan(-\tfrac1{3\sqrt3}))\\
=\frac\pi{2\sqrt3}\arctan(4\sqrt3)
$$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that
$$\int_{1/3}^{3}\frac{\arctan(1/x)}{x^2-x+1}dx,\quad t = 1/x$$
$$=\int_{3}^{1/3}\frac{\arctan(t)}{(1/t)^2-(1/t)+1}\frac{-1}{t^2}dt$$
$$=-\int_{3}^{1/3}\frac{\arctan(t)}{1-t+t^2}dt$$
$$=\int_{1/3}^{3}\frac{\arctan(t)}{t^2-t+1}dt.$$

So, the (*) integral is the same as the original.